# my_sql, need to delete 1st row

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked this up here and on the web in general and not found an answer.

For reasons I'll not go into, I need to delete the top row from a mysql
database table, then refresh the page.

The delete is always for the top row, and independent of the row's content,
so doing a select where  is useless.

Seems to me I should be able to call (in my php code) this:

```
mysql_deleterow(0);  // delete the top row from the table
```

and be done with it.  But oh no -- no such call that I can find.

Is there a way to just delete a table row independent of its content?
(please reread above where I say 'for reasons I'll not go into' if you
feel an urge to ask me 'Why do you want to do that?')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this query to delete the row from the database:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM table_name LIMIT 1');
```

To refresh the page:

```
header("Refresh: 0; url=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 5):

Will it work for you:
`DELETE FROM your_table [ORDER BY field_name] LIMIT 1;`

You can omit `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1`.  If this doesn't do what you want, you can do something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY XXXX ASC LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1`.  This second way will allow you to control which row is the top one.

Comment: Actually, and again I'm not going to discuss why, but my code treats the table like an array -- it does SELECT * then just displays each row one after the other using mysql_fetch_row().   So in the same order that fetch_row() retrieves a row -- I just want to delete the first row that fetch_row() retrieves.  Does that help explain what I want to do?

Comment: @wantthebest, I'd process the rows then use `TRUNCATE table` to remove all rows once you're done.  It'll be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "top row". You will need to define what that is yourself, for example the one with the lowest id, the oldest timestamp or similar (and you will need to create those fields yourself as well).

If we define the top row as the one with the lowest id, we can delete it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

You can also do this without the ORDER BY clause, but in that case the row which gets deleted is undefined. This may or may not delete the "top row":

```
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1;
```